# Sikuli : NameError: name 'click' is not defined

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I have this java installed:

```
java version "1.8.0_391"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_391-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.391-b13, mixed mode)
```

and running SikulixIDE-2.0.5 on Windows 10 64bits.

I tried a simple "Hello world" script :

```
from sikuli import *
click("1699824246719.png")
type("hello world")
```

but when I try to run it it’s giving me the error "NameError: name 'click' is not defined"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start it from a commandline window using:

```
java -jar <sikulixide ... jar> ... parameter
```

RaiMan from SikuliX

Comment: Same problem. When the IDE is starting, I see in the Message window "[error] Mouse: not useable (blocked)".

So maybe it’s linked to this problem: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/699797 (maybe, as for me, click() is not working at all).

I’m running Sikuli on a Dell xps 15 laptop.